# Remove extraneous spaces with `gsub` for `print.xtable`

Tags: r, gsub, xtable

I am new to R development, and have to modify some existing code. Specifically, I need to change a `print()` call so that it removes extraneous consecutive space characters.

I've found the `sanitize.text.function` parameter, and have successfully passed it my custom function to the print() function. And it does what I need it to do. That code is as follows:

```
print(xtable(x,...),type="html",
      sanitize.text.function = function(s) gsub(" {2,}", "", s),...)
```

Now what I am trying to do is extract the "anonymous" / "inline" function code into a named function like so...

```
clean <- function(s) { gsub(" {2,}", "", s) }
print(xtable(x,...),type="html",sanitize.text.function = clean(s),...)
```

However, when I execute this, I get the following:

> Error in gsub(" {2,}", "", s) : object 's' not found

The desire to define a function is two-fold:

1. to create a reusable block of code that could be referenced in other places, and
2. the ability to add more `gsub()` or similar executions that may be needed,

For example,

```
clean <- function(s) { 
    gsub(" {2,}", "", s)
    gsub(">(.*?:)", "<span style=float:left>\1</span>", s)
}

print(xtable(x,...),type="html",sanitize.text.function = clean(s),...)
```

Comment: did you try with `sanitize.text.function = clean`? You don't have to specify the `(s)`, as that is the function argument. R will look for an object s and won't find it. `sanitize.text.function` takes a function as argument, so the name `clean` should suffice.

Comment: Also unless you're inside of a function "..." doesn't make any sense to have as a parameter.

Comment: If you want to execute both blocks of code, you should change first line to s <- gsub(" {2,}","",s).

Comment: I generally use `trim` from package:gdata for removal of leading and trailing spaces.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `sanitize.text.function` expects a *function* yet you pass a result of `clean(s)` instead of the function (the argument will be evaluated!). So you can either use `sanitize.text.function=clean` or if you need to re-map arguments `sanitize.text.function=function(x) clean(x)` which is the lambda (unnamed) function construct you were looking for (the latter makes only sense for something more complex, obviously).